# Как выводить в QTextBrowser информацию из виджетов, которые находятся в QLayout?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, qlayout, qtextbrowser

У меня есть основной виджет `Widget2`, в котором выбирается количество мужчин, женщин и режим.

Далее, нажав кнопку **`"Добавить"`**, в `self.verticalLayout_5` добавляется соответствующее количество виджетов `Widget3`, равное сумме количества мужчин и женщин на предыдущем этапе (см.screen_№1 - screen_№3).

**screen_№1**:
[image: screen_№1]

**screen_№2**:

[image: screen_№2]

**screen_№3**:

[image: screen_№3]

Далее у каждого созданного виджета `Widget3` есть два атрибута `атрибут1` и `атрибут2`, которые меняет пользователь (см.screen_№4)

**screen_№4**:

[image: screen_№4]

---

**Вопрос**, как сделать так, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку **`"Рассчитать"`** выводилось: (см.screen_№5)

**screen_№5**:

[image: screen_№5]

**Widget2.py**

```
class Ui_Form1(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form1):
        Form1.setObjectName("Form1")
        Form1.resize(700, 709)
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form1)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form1)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.line.setLineWidth(1)
        self.line.setMidLineWidth(0)
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.line)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form1)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HouschkaRoundedAlt 9")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Form1)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HouschkaRoundedAlt 9")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.comboBox.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form1)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HouschkaRoundedAlt 9")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.comboBox_3 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Form1)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HouschkaRoundedAlt 9")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.comboBox_3.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox_3.setObjectName("comboBox_3")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.comboBox_3)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form1)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HouschkaRoundedAlt 9")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Form1)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HouschkaRoundedAlt 9")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.comboBox_2.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox_2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(0, "")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.comboBox_2)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form1)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HouschkaRoundedAlt 9")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.pushButton_3.setFlat(False)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form1)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.line_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form1)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_6.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_6.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HouschkaRoundedAlt 9")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_6)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form1)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_5.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_5.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HouschkaRoundedAlt 9")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_5)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form1)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HouschkaRoundedAlt 9")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_5)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form1)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HouschkaRoundedAlt 9")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.line_4 = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form1)
        self.line_4.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.line_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_4.setObjectName("line_4")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.line_4)
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Form1)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.textBrowser.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.textBrowser.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.textBrowser)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form1)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HouschkaRoundedAlt 9")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)

        self.retranslateUi(Form1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form1)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form1):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form1.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form1", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form1", "Выберите количество мужчин"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Form1", "0"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Form1", "1"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("Form1", "2"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("Form1", "3"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("Form1", "4"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(5, _translate("Form1", "5"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(6, _translate("Form1", "6"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(7, _translate("Form1", "7"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(8, _translate("Form1", "8"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(9, _translate("Form1", "9"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(10, _translate("Form1", "10"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form1", "Выберите количество женщин"))
        self.comboBox_3.setItemText(0, _translate("Form1", "0"))
        self.comboBox_3.setItemText(1, _translate("Form1", "1"))
        self.comboBox_3.setItemText(2, _translate("Form1", "2"))
        self.comboBox_3.setItemText(3, _translate("Form1", "3"))
        self.comboBox_3.setItemText(4, _translate("Form1", "4"))
        self.comboBox_3.setItemText(5, _translate("Form1", "5"))
        self.comboBox_3.setItemText(6, _translate("Form1", "6"))
        self.comboBox_3.setItemText(7, _translate("Form1", "7"))
        self.comboBox_3.setItemText(8, _translate("Form1", "8"))
        self.comboBox_3.setItemText(9, _translate("Form1", "9"))
        self.comboBox_3.setItemText(10, _translate("Form1", "10"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form1", "Режим"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(1, _translate("Form1", "1"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(2, _translate("Form1", "2"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(3, _translate("Form1", "3"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form1", "Добавить"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Form1", "Кто?"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Form1", "Атрибут1"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form1", "Атрибут2"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form1", "Рассчитать"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form1", "Назад"))
```

**Widget3.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form3(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form3):
        Form3.setObjectName("Form3")
        Form3.resize(610, 266)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form3)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form3)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_7.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_7.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HouschkaRoundedAlt 9")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_7)
        self.comboBox_5 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Form3)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.comboBox_5.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.comboBox_5.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HouschkaRoundedAlt 9")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.comboBox_5.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox_5.setObjectName("comboBox_5")
        self.comboBox_5.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_5.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_5.addItem("")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.comboBox_5)
        self.comboBox_4 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Form3)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.comboBox_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.comboBox_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HouschkaRoundedAlt 9")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.comboBox_4.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox_4.setEditable(False)
        self.comboBox_4.setObjectName("comboBox_4")
        self.comboBox_4.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_4.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_4.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_4.addItem("")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.comboBox_4)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)

        self.retranslateUi(Form3)
        self.comboBox_5.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.comboBox_4.setCurrentIndex(1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form3)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form3):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form3.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form3", "Form"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("Form3", "TextLabel"))
        self.comboBox_5.setItemText(0, _translate("Form3", "Меньше обычного"))
        self.comboBox_5.setItemText(1, _translate("Form3", "Средне"))
        self.comboBox_5.setItemText(2, _translate("Form3", "Больше обычного"))
        self.comboBox_4.setItemText(0, _translate("Form3", "Меньше обычного"))
        self.comboBox_4.setItemText(1, _translate("Form3", "Средне"))
        self.comboBox_4.setItemText(2, _translate("Form3", "Больше обычного"))
        self.comboBox_4.setItemText(3, _translate("Form3", "Не пьет"))
```

**MAIN.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from File1 import Ui_Form1
from File2 import Ui_Form3
import sys


class Widget2(QtWidgets.QWidget,Ui_Form1):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget2, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.add)

    # def qwert(self):
    #     self.textBrowser.setText(self.woman_table[1].comboBox_4.currentTextChanged())

    def add(self):
        self.man = int(self.comboBox.currentText())
        self.woman = int(self.comboBox_3.currentText())
        self.woman_table = []
        self.man_table = []
        for i in range(self.man):
            self.man_table.append(Widget3(self,'Мужчина_{}'.format(i+1)))
        for i in range(self.woman):
            self.woman_table.append(Widget3(self,'Женщина_{}'.format(i+1)))
        i = 0
        while i != self.man:
            self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.man_table[i])
            i += 1
        i = 0
        while i != self.woman:
            self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.woman_table[i])
            i += 1
        # self.qwert()

class Widget3(QtWidgets.QWidget,Ui_Form3):
    def __init__(self,parent,text):
        super(Widget3, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.text = text
        self.parent = parent
        self.label_7.setText(self.text)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = Widget2()
application.show()
app.setStyle('Fusion')
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я отметил для вас изменения, которые я внес. Проверьте:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from File1 import Ui_Form1          
from File2 import Ui_Form3         


class Widget2(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form1):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget2, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.add)
# +++
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.calculate)                 # +++

    # def qwert(self):
    #     self.textBrowser.setText(self.woman_table[1].comboBox_4.currentTextChanged())

    def add(self):
        self.man = int(self.comboBox.currentText())
        self.woman = int(self.comboBox_3.currentText())
        print(self.man, self.woman)
        self.woman_table = []
        self.man_table = []
        for i in range(self.man):
            widget3 = Widget3(self,'Мужчина_{}'.format(i+1))
#            self.man_table.append(Widget3(self,'Мужчина_{}'.format(i+1)))
            self.man_table.append(widget3)
            
        for i in range(self.woman):
            widget3 = Widget3(self,'Женщина_{}'.format(i+1))
#            self.woman_table.append(Widget3(self,'Женщина_{}'.format(i+1)))
            self.woman_table.append(widget3)
        i = 0
        while i != self.man:
            self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.man_table[i])
            i += 1
        i = 0
        while i != self.woman:
            self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.woman_table[i])
            i += 1
        # self.qwert()
        
# +++        
    def calculate(self):
        for man in self.man_table:
            text = f"{man.text}: {man.comboBox_5.currentText()}, {man.comboBox_4.currentText()}"
            self.textBrowser.append(text)           
           
        for woman in self.woman_table:
            text = f"{woman.text}: {woman.comboBox_5.currentText()}, {woman.comboBox_4.currentText()}" 
            self.textBrowser.append(text)        


class Widget3(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form3):
    def __init__(self, parent, text):
        super(Widget3, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.text = text
        self.parent = parent
        self.label_7.setText(self.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    application = Widget2()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, это то, что нужно, спасибо огромное!